# C# How to catch an exception on generic abstract class constructor

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I am unable to catch an exception from a generic abstract class in the client app. The reason I want the exception to be thrown in the constructor is that the config file functionality needs to be the same in the derived classes and therefore I don't see a reason to implement this in every derived class. The exception should be handled in the overarching generic class `AgentModule<T>` however, this is not the case for a reason I am unaware.

I can catch the exception when I move the code to a method and invoke from the client class.

The abstract class:

```
public abstract class Importer
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract string Description { get; }

    private System.Configuration.Configuration _customConfig;

    public Importer()
    {
        string customConfigFile = this.GetType().Assembly.Location + ".config";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(customConfigFile))
        {
            System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = customConfigFile;
            _customConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("Could not load configuration file: " + customConfigFile);
        }
    }

    public abstract void Load(ILogger logger);
}
```

The generic overarching class:

```
public class AgentModule<T> : ModuleBase where T : Importer, new()
{
    private Importer _importer;

    public override void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            _importer = (Importer)Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Derived class:

```
public class XLoad : Importer
{
    public override string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public override string Description { get { return _description; } }

    private string _name;
    private string _description;  

    public XLoad()
    {
        _name = "Load";
        _description = "some desc";

    }

    public override void Load(ILogger logger)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am loading");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that no exception is thrown because the file does exist?

Comment: Is this your actual code or are you actually catching `FileNotFoundException` in the base class? `Activator.CreateInstance` will throw a `TargetInvocationException` if the invoked constructor throws.

Comment: @Igor, no the VS shows `FileNotFoundException was ungandled by user code`

Comment: @Lee, in the base class I am catching just an `Exception`

Comment: Are you doing this in the debugger? The debugger will break on the first-chance exception but should enter the catch block if you continue.

Comment: @Lee, Yes I am debuggin and the VS never enters the `catch` block.

Comment: Actually it should also fail on `_customConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None)`  As the file is empty right now.

Comment: @Dimt, try removing all other code from constructor and leave only exception throwing. Check in the debugger that it really goes to the constructor and throws an exception.

Comment: @ams4fy I put the break point on the that line and it goes to the constructor.

Comment: @Dimt, your code seems to be correct for me. I've just checked it locally and it caught the exception. How does the derived class look? Can it be that your code executes in ModuleBase's Run method, not in your override one?

Comment: @Dimt I was able to simulate the crash when I created a sample code with your classes targeting .NET 4.0. It did crash in an unhandled way in the ctor of Importer class. But this crash went away the moment I targeted this project to .NET 4.5 or .NET 4.5.2. I was not able to recreate the issue if I created a fresh project in .NET 4.5 or .NET 4.5.2. This seems to me like a CLR bug. Can you simply retarget the project to say 4.5.2 and see?

Comment: @ams4fy I have edited my question to include the derived class. Please also note that I am able to catch the exception when I move the code to a method and invoke from the client class.

Comment: @Abey I am already targeting  .NET 4.5.1 however, will try with a higher version.

Comment: @Abey, no bug for me for any version higher then 4.0, could you please share you code? Do you use console app?

Dimt, If it's reproducible from method in the client class, then the question is how do you execute it? Interesting thing.

Comment: @ams4fy yes I did create a console app targeting .net 4.0. Here is the code I wrote: http://pasted.co/8f260684

Comment: @Abey, not reproducible for any .net version for me :) Whatever fresh solution was created or retargeted switch was made

Comment: @Dimt, visual studio creates config file by default with the exactly name you check. Do you run your client class in another assembly? Or did any other things that could affect location of config?

Comment: @ams4fy Strange.. Another observation is - This 2nd time I used VS2010 and I created a Console app. By default, it targeted .NET 4.0 Client Profile. This scenario crashed consistently. But when I changed, this project to target .NET 4 (not the client profile), the crash stopped. Which VS did you use?

Comment: Not related to your question, but one usually makes constructors of `abstract` classes `protected`, not `public`. This is because they can only be called from deriving classes (you cannot "new" an abstract class except through "newing" a concrete inheriting class). So `public Importer()` should be `protected Importer()`.

Comment: @ams4fy it's to much to explain however I am doing a basic check by changing the file extension in `string customConfigFile = this.GetType().Assembly.Location + ".config";` to something else. The actual DLL sits in another assembly and is referenced from a console app. Also as suggested by @Abey in my constructor I only left the `throw exception` line.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks for the suggestion,  still a lot to learn for me re best practices :)

Comment: @ams4fy The crash is consistent for me when I create a fresh console app on .NET 4.0 (VS 2015). The moment I retarget the framework to something else higher, the crash goes away. Strangely, it doesnt come back if I retarget it back to .NET 4.0

Comment: That seems like an awful lot of logic for the constructor.  Why not pass in the already created Configuration object and make the job of creating it the responsibility of another class.  It's better to work with explicit rather than implicit dependencies.

Comment: @Abey, it's not a defect. The reason is when you switch your .net version app.config is created and put into your root folder. Then, after building it is copied to bin folder and your if statement passes (dont' throw an exception). When you switch back - app.config is still there.

Comment: @ams4fy you are right about the .config file - my bad. But the point is given an exception thrown in the ctor of Importer, it is not not caught in the catch of AgentModule.Run() for me. Are you saying that for you if an exception occurs in the ctor of Importer class, it is handled by the CLR and is caught in the Catch of Agent.Run()? btw, ctor of my version of Importer now just have the throw Exception(..) code.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio debugger will not catch any exception for whatever happens within Activator.CreateInstance(). But if you execute the exe manually/programmatically, this exception will be handled. You can even get the exception thrown at the constructor of the Importer class from the InnerException at AgentModule.Run()

```
try
    {
       _importer = (Importer)Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
catch (Exception e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

         if(e.InnerException != null)
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message );
      }
```

Comment: My VS debugger catches the exception of Activator.CreateInstance like any other one.

Comment: That is exactly my problem as described by Abey. Have the same behavior, it works fine when executing console app manually.